# How can I change/add params on a store

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs

On a sencha-touch, here's is my store declaration

```
Ext.regStore('newsStore',  {
    model: 'News',
    autoLoad: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: '../news/list.form?format=json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: ''
        }
    },                        
});
```

How can I modify params? I tried

```
params:{ format: 'json'}
```

But its doesn't work!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Store declaration**

```
new Ext.data.Store({
model:'prj.models.ContactInfo',
storeId:'contactInfoId',
proxy:{
    type:'ajax',
    url:'/GetContactInfoByID',
    reader:{
        type:'json'
    },
    extraParams:{
        format:'json'
    },
    listeners:{
        exception:function(proxy, response, orientation){
            console.error('Failure Notification', response.responseText);
            Ext.Msg.alert('Loading failed', response.statusText);
        }
    }
}   
});
```

**Adding params to proxy and read ajax store**

```
prj.stores.contactInfoId.getProxy().extraParams.partyID = options.partyID;
prj.stores.contactInfoId.getProxy().extraParams.eventName = options.eventName;
prj.stores.contactInfoId.read();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: it works, great thank you. Its perfect, exactly what I'm looking for :). I need to have init param and change with by options/buttons. Thank you. What's the difference between the method read() and load() on a store object?

Comment: both has the same functionality i.e make an ajax call and fill the store. using load you have Optional config object, passed into the Ext.data.Operation object before loading.

Comment: In Sencha Touch 2.0.1.1 proxy.extraParams = {...} not working.
Use proxy.setExtraParams({...}) instead.

Answer (score 3):

**For dynamically setting extra parameters:**

If you want to set single parameter at a time, you can use following

```
var proxy= myStore.getProxy();
proxy.setExtraParam('param1', 'value 1' );
proxy.setExtraParam('param2' , 'value 2' );
myStore.load();
```

If you want to set multiple parameters at a time, you can use following

```
proxy.setExtraParams({
     'param1':'value 1',
     'param2':'value 2'
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try using `extraParams`:

```
Ext.regStore('newsStore',  {
    model: 'News',
    autoLoad: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: '../news/list.form',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: ''
        },
        extraParams: {
            format: 'json'
        }
    },                        
});
```

Comment: It works. Have you an idea how can I modify param? I retrieve the store like that: Ext.StoreMgr.get('newsStore').load(); Its possible to change extraParams? (Ext.StoreMgr.get('newsStore').proxy.extraParams....?)

Comment: Ok, answered by mehul9595 (up on this post)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you a more elegant solution, the Sencha way to do that:

```
//Take your store
var store = Ext.StoreMgr.get('YOUR_STORE_ID');

//Apply the params
Ext.apply(store.getProxy().extraParams, {
    partyID: options.partyID,
    eventName: options.eventName
});

//Reload your store
store.contactInfoId.read();
```

Hope this helps.