# Passing values from Store to the PHP

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I am trying to pass a value to the PHP server side. My Store code is as follows;

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.MyArrayStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    requires: [
        'MyApp.model.MyMOD'
    ],

    config: {
        autoLoad: true,
        model: 'MyApp.model.MyMOD',
        storeId: 'MyArrayStore',
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            actionMethods: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost/mm/app/php/res.php',
            reader: {
                type: 'json'
            }
        },
        listeners: [
            {
                fn: 'onArraystoreBeforeLoad',
                event: 'beforeload'
            }
        ]
    },

    onArraystoreBeforeLoad: function(store, operation, eOpts) {
        this.proxy.extraParams.VALUES1 = "pass some name here"; 
    }

});
```

PHP Code

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);

require_once 'conn.php'; // contains the connection

$v = $_POST['VALUES1'];
echo json_encode($v);

?>
```

What gets returned is `null`, and not the value that i am passing from the store (which is `pass some name here`).

How can i correct this ?

**UPDATE**

```
Request URL:http://localhost/test/app/php/res.php?_dc=1373343459447
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:23
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Host:localhost
Origin:http://localhost
Referer:http://localhost/test/app.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Query String Parametersview sourceview URL encoded
_dc:1373343459447
Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
page:1
start:0
limit:25
Response Headersview source
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:24
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Tue, 09 Jul 2013 04:17:39 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=96
Server:Apache/2.2.14 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8l PHP/5.3.1 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.3.1
```

Comment: did you checked is there a error in console.. because i thing there should be an error..

Comment: Yes there is. The error is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'extraParams' of undefined `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `this.proxy` try `this.getProxy()`.

I find the console very useful for this sort of thing. In my own app running `Ext.getStore('MyStore').proxy;` gets me undefined whereas `Ext.getStore('MyStore').getProxy()` gets me my proxy.

Use the console, for me it is the most valuable development tool next the API.

Good luck, Brad

Comment: Yes, i tried your approach too, but i am still getting an error: `MyJsonReader1 unable to read data.
Open in Browser: http://localhost......` . 

I think the the reason is because PHP is returning a null (when i echo the response it returns null). So i guess the value of `VALUES1` is not picked at the PHP end. Any clue how to solve this ?

Comment: Use the network tab in the developer console to see what params are actually getting passed.

Comment: It seems it is not getting POSTed (passed).

Comment: You mean the `Store` ?. If so i have added it above. When the page is loaded it should send a request to the php and display records on the view.

Comment: I don't have access to test this syntax but I have done something similar to this. Call something like `getProxy().setUrl(getProxy().getUrl() + '?EXTRA1="some name here"')`. Again sorry for the syntax but that logic should work. If you don't need the 'some name here' parameter to by dynamic you could also just add it to the url in the proxy directly.

Comment: No but still there seems to be some problem. I get the same output.

Comment: Does this help? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6120713/how-can-i-change-add-params-on-a-store](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6120713/how-can-i-change-add-params-on-a-store)

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the way you setting extraParams.. in this case i will using

```
  store.getProxy().setExtraParam('VALUES1','pass some name here');
```

If you need to send more than one parameter then use setExtraParams

```
  var param = { VALUES1: 'param1', VALUES2 : 'param2'};
  store.getProxy().setExtraParams(param);
```

**So full Store code**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.MyArrayStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    requires: [
        'MyApp.model.MyMOD'
    ],

    config: {
        autoLoad: true,
        model: 'MyApp.model.MyMOD',
        storeId: 'MyArrayStore',
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            actionMethods: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost/mm/app/php/res.php',
            reader: {
                type: 'json'
            }
        },
        listeners: [
            {
                fn: 'onArraystoreBeforeLoad',
                event: 'beforeload'
            }
        ]
    },

    onArraystoreBeforeLoad: function(store, operation, eOpts) {
        store.getProxy().setExtraParam('VALUES1 ','pass some name here');
    }

});
```

Comment: I still get an error: `MyJsonReader1 unable to read data.
Open in Browser: http://localhost......` . The reason is that the PHP is returning a null. So i guess the value of VALUES1 is not picked at the PHP end. Any clue ?

Comment: Should it `actionMethods` or `actionMethod` ?